# WPF MVVM view becomes null on on button click

Tags: wpf, mvvm

application is in MVVM and WPF

I have a window which have a submit button. window is opening in some parent window. When ok button is clicked then the value which i already injected in view model get null.

view is in this format:

```
 <UserControl>
    <Grid Background="{x:Null}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource   AddViewModelKey}}">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     </Grid>


    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="buttonOK"  TabIndex="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Ok" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding Command}" Height="22" FontSize="12" Width="90" Grid.Column="2"/> 
          </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

and in view model I have:

```
    private AddtView _view { get; set; }
    private IAddServices _service;
    public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
    ApplicationWindow parentWindow { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public AddViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveData);
        //_view = new AddAirCraftView();
        //parentWindow = new ApplicationWindow("Tile") { WindowContent = _view, IsResizable = false };
        // To Do
    }


    public AddViewModel(AddView View, IAddServices Service)
    {
       _view = View;
        _service = Service;
       parentWindow = new ApplicationWindow("Title") { WindowContent = _view, IsResizable = false };
       parentWindow.CloseButtonClick += parentWindow_CloseButtonClick;

    }
```

when i click on OK button parent Window becomes null. From where it set the null i am not able to find. I am implementing RelayCommand:ICommand. Please look into it where it is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: you set the button command to Command instead of AddCommand

Answer (score 0):

Just like Bizz said.You didnt set Button command to AddCommand and can you give your full code? i didnt know when  AddViewModel(AddView View, IAddServices Service) method is get called.is it get called?,if not,that why your parent Window becomes null, it didnt get to set.

Comment: when i click on ok button .then default constructor is get called how can i call constructor with parameter that time.